# What are all the distinct “capacities” of the City of London Corporation?

Tags: city-of-london

A comment on another question refers to the COLC’s port authority, local authority and police force capacities. What other capacities does it have? And what defines the notion of a “capacity”?

Comment: The dictionary defines [capacity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capacity). Have you looked at the Wikipedia page on the City of London Corporation or its own web page?

Answer (score 3):

One of them, is to manage various parks and open spaces, which are not in the City of London (the "Square Mile").

Please see [List of parks and open spaces managed by the City of London Corporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_parks_and_open_spaces_managed_by_the_City_of_London_Corporation).

An example is [Burnham Beeches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnham_Beeches) in Buckinghamshire.